# How to get the transaction ID in virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I am trying to develop a plugin for the VIRTUEMART that will add a new payment method - INTERSWITCH webpay into the website.

But i am a bit confused about the process. I was looking for the transaction ID in this case.

Can anyone help me which field in the database is going to provide me with the Transaction ID of the order.

Thanks
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `vm_order_payment` has the column `order_payment_trans_id`.